# Constructor/destructor order dependencies between data members

Tags: c++, raii

I'm creating a C++ class for executing SSH commands, using libssh2.

The life cycle of a libssh2 SSH session goes through these stages:

1. Initialization (acquires local resources)
2. Handshake/Authentication (establishes an SSH session on the remote
   host)
3. Disconnect (terminates SSH session on the remote host)
4. Free (releases local resources; if necessary, also performs step 3).

Before step 1, we have to open a socket, which we pass to libssh2 in step 2. From then on, we don't need to pass the socket anymore, as libssh2 will store a reference to it. After step 4, we can close the socket.

I'm exposing this through a class (`SSHSession`), and I'd like *setup* (steps 1 and 2) to happen on ctor and *teardown* (steps 3 and 4) to happen on dtor (since step 2 is time-consuming, this will allow me to keep a pool of sessions open and reuse it to execute commands).

My first attempt concentrated all the code on `SSHSession`, and its ctor quickly became a mess, with the "if this step fails, then we must see what has already been done and undo it" routine; the dtor was not as complex, but I still found it too "busy".

Then, I divided the work across several classes, implementing RAII for each acquire/release step, namely:

- Steps 1 and 4.
- Steps 2 and 3.

I created a class `SessionConnection` that implemented steps 2 and 3, and had a member of type `SessionHandle` that implemented steps 1 and 4; it also had the socket as a data member, creating the first order dependency on ctor/dtor - the socket could not be destroyed before the `SessionHandle` member.

As I was considering my design, I figured I could arrange steps 2 and 3 like this:

> 2.1. Handshake (establishes an SSH session on the remote host)
>
> 2.2. Authentication
>
> 3. Disconnect (terminates SSH session on the remote host)

Which means I could further simplify my `SessionConnection` class, implementing another class to perform RAII on steps 2.1 and 3, and ending up with something like this:

- Class `SSHSession` has a `SessionConnection` data member.
- Class `SessionConnection` implements step 2.2.
- `SessionConnection` has a socket data member.
- `SessionConnection` has a `SessionHandle` data member, that implements steps 1 and 4. This must be destroyed before the socket.
- `SessionConnection` has a `RemoteSessionHandle` data member, that implements steps 2.1 and 3. This must be created after, and destroyed before, the `SessionHandle` data member.

This greatly simplifies my ctors/dtors, courtesy of RAII. And I find conceptually sound; if, on the one hand, we can look at these as states the SSH session goes through, on the other hand, we can also see them as resources (local, remote) we're managing.

However, I now have a strict construction/destruction order in `SessionConnection`, and while I believe it's an improvement (and I found nothing in my research that stated "this is evil", only "this should be clearly documented"), I'm interested in other opinions, and I'll happily accept info/pointers about possible alternatives to this design.

What I've looked at, so far:

- ScopeGuard, ScopeExit. It's a similar mechanism, I didn't find
  anything I could use as an improvement on my design.
- State Machine. I couldn't find a way to simplify the design with it,
  and it didn't solve one problem RAII does, namely, cleanup if something fails.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have the right design.  The only thing to remember is that construction is in the order of declaration in the class, not in the order of initializations in the initialization list of the constructor.  (For this reason, it's good to ensure that both use the same order.)

Comment: @James Yes, I've got that part covered. And on gcc I'm using `-Wall`, which enables `-Wreorder`, so no problem there, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be nothing fundamentally wrong with this design.

If you would like to remove the restriction on the construction/destruction order of the members of `SessionConnection`, you could do the following:

- Class `SSHSession`

  - implements step 2.2
  - has a `SSHConnection` member
- Class `SSHConnection`

  - implements step 2.1 and 3
  - has a `LocalSessionHandle` member
- Class `LocalSessionHandle`

  - implements step 1 and 4
  - has a `Socket` member

The defined construction/destruction order of members and their containing classes ensures the steps are taken in the right order.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll keep it noted. I just don't like the way it models the relationship between the classes - e.g., it creates an artificial _has-a_ relationship between the remote resources class and the local resources class. Still, a good alternative.