# Move semantics and pointer members (dependency)

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Consider the following class:

```
class SessionConnection
{
...
private:
    SessionHandle sessionHandle;
    RemoteSessionHandle remoteSessionHandle;
};
```

Its ctor is something like this:

```
SessionConnection::SessionConnection(whatever) :
..., sessionHandle{some_more_whatever}, remoteSessionHandle{sessionHandle}, ...
{
...
}
```

`RemoteSessionHandle` looks like this:

```
class RemoteSessionHandle
{
...
private:
    SessionHandle* sessionHandle;
};

RemoteSessionHandle::RemoteSessionHandle(SessionHandle const& pSessionHandle) :
..., sessionHandle{&pSessionHandle}
{
...
}
```

**Note:** These classes have more members, but I'm trying to stick to the point.

Upon construction, `SessionConnection` injects `sessionHandle` into `remoteSessionHandle`, which keeps a pointer to it.

However, I then have a problem with the move constructor. Before a move, I have this:

```
movedFromSessionConnection           movedToSessionConnection
+------------------------------+     +----------------------------+
| movedFromSessionHandle       |     | movedToSessionHandle       |
|            ^                 |     |            ^               |
|            |                 |     |            |               |
| movedFromRemoteSessionHandle |     | movedToRemoteSessionHandle |
+------------------------------+     +----------------------------+
```

Each RemoteSessionHandle points to its SessionHandle. After a move, I get this:

```
movedFromSessionConnection --- mv ---> movedToSessionConnection
+------------------------------+     +----------------------------+
| movedFromSessionHandle ---- mv ----> movedToSessionHandle       |
|            ^ -----------------------------------+               |
|                                                 |               |
| movedFromRemoteSessionHandle - mv -> movedToRemoteSessionHandle |
+------------------------------+     +----------------------------+
```

The contents of `movedFromRemoteSessionHandle` are moved to `movedToRemoteSessionHandle`, so it now points to `movedFromSessionHandle`. Which is in an unknown state, after being moved to `movedToSessionHandle`.

I've considered the following solutions:

1. Exclude the pointer from RemoteSessionHandle's move ctor. I find this a bit "smelly", since I've yet to find an example of a move ctor that doesn't move - or act upon - all data members.
2. Remove SessionHandle from SessionConnection, and make it a member of
   RemoteSessionHandle, instead.
3. Implement a "regular" move ctor in RemoteSessionHandle ("regular"
   meaning moving all the data members), and have SessionConnection's move ctor
   reseat the pointer in RemoteSessionHandle.

Options 2 and 3 are possible in this context, because these classes are strongly coupled by design. However, I've then considered what could I do if that weren't the case.

I've looked all over the web, and I found no one else with this problem, so my first instinct would be to believe I'm overlooking something pretty obvious (or I lack the google-fu for this particular search).

Am I overlooking anything obvious? Is this a non-problem, easily solved by whatever I may be overlooking?

**Edit:**

Following Igor's comment, I've decided to add some more context. I'm using these classes to create a libssh2 session using boost.asio. The creation of a libssh2 session goes through several states, and setup and shutdown are symmetric enough that I can use RAII to manage it (I detailed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287601/constructor-destructor-order-dependencies-between-data-members)).

RemoteSessionHandle needs SessionHandle because the latter owns the `LIBSSH2_SESSION*` that will be required by the former to operate, hence the dependency.

Comment: What other contexts is `RemoteSessionHandle` used in?  Instead of injecting that pointer, you could use CRTP with `RemoteSessionHandle<SessionHandle>` which removes the requirement to track the `SessionHandle` via an explicit pointer.  Second, doesn't the same problem occur in your copy constructor?

Comment: You have a class that wants to maintain an unusual invariant (for unclear reasons) - that one member always points to the other. There is nothing wrong with writing unusual constructors in order to maintain unusual invariants, if that's what it takes.

Comment: @Yakk I don't expect to use these classes anywhere else. I should've made that clearer, sorry. If I understood correctly what you're suggesting, I would get a result similar to my alternative #2 (although your suggestion is much more flexible). These classes aren't copyable. The reason I'm making them moveable is because I'm going to use them into a pool, and I may need them to be moved.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I've updated the question with some more info. I considered this design because it seemed a simple way to inject a dependency that is not owned by the receiver (i.e., RemoteSessionHandle). However, one of the things I'm trying to understand here is what other options there are for managing these kind of dependencies in C++.